# _search CJK term in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elasticsearch not support query cjk character in url ?
I need to query term 北京(Beijing in chinese) for field(name) in index (old_merge_result). The following query seems not working. ES would retur

GET /old_merge_result/tempid/_search?q=name:北京

ES would return :

```html
{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "child \"uri\" fails because [\"uri\" must be a valid uri]",
   "validation": {
      "source": "query",
      "keys": [
         "uri"
      ]
   }
}
```

Instead, query through the following would return exactly what i want.

```html
GET /old_merge_result/tempid/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "北京"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So is there any way query through  url like old_merge_result/tempid/_search?q=name:北京 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to use [percent-encoding/URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to pass cjk characters as query parameters

For the above example it would be :

```
GET /old_merge_result/tempid/_search?q=name:%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! acceptI Just realise those query is made by plugin sense, and it doesn't do urlencode like browser did. Thanks.

Comment: sure np ! glad it helped.